# Тире/дефис между арабскими цифрами

Tags: тире-дефис

Известно, что между арабскими цифрами ставится тире: *1734—1856 гг.*, *20—40 %*; *1—3 дня*.

Но если между числами **нет промежутка**, что нужно ставить?

*8-/—9*, *11-/—12 %*, *23-/—24 °C* и т. д.

А если подразумевается, что можно поставить союз *или*, то что тогда?

*5-/—8 дней*, *20-/—30 %*, 10-/—20  °C и т. д.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Что вам конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Все эти слеши, для меня непонятные.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Слеши показывают, выбрать дефис или тире. Сначала стоит знак дефиса, потом слеш в значении «или», потом тире.

Comment: Что значит «между числами нет промежутка»?

Comment: Это значит, что между числами нельзя поставить даже единицу. Между 8 и 10 можно? Да, можно 1 число поставить. А между 8 и 9 можно? Нельзя. Это и имеется в виду

Comment: Вряд ли можно, так как 1 - 2 - это не отдельные цифры, а промежуток. Хотя, я ставлю везде дефисную черту, просто потому что тире не известно где. Дефис - это сращение. Тире указывает на пропуск чего-то. Если или, лучше написать один или два градуса. Но это относится прямо к грамотным текстам, не к чатам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[6.1.5. Интервал значений](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html#id-6%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-615%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора):

> **Обозначение интервала значений.** Для обозначения интервала значений ставят: а) многоточие; б) тире; в) знак ÷; г) предлог *от* перед первым числом и до — перед вторым. Напр.: *Длиной 5... 10 метров; Длиной 5—10 метров; Длиной 5÷10 метров; Длиной от 5 до 10 метров.*
> Предпочтительным для изданий техн. и науч. (в области точных и естественных наук) лит. является стандартный знак многоточие (**...**) между числами в цифровой форме.
> В техн. лит. по традиции допустимо применять знак **÷** между числами в цифровой форме.
> Тире и предлоги употребляются в изданиях гуманитарной и публицистической лит.
> <...>
> **Употребление дефиса.** Когда два числа в словесной форме (прописью) означают не «от такого-то до такого-то числа», а «то ли то, то ли другое число», то между числительными ставят дефис. Напр.: *У дома стояло машин пять-шестъ.* В цифровой форме сохраняется тире: *машин 5—6*.

Получается: ***8–9, 11–12 %, 23–24 °C.***

Если имеется в виду *5 или 8 дней, 20 или 30 %, 10 или 20 °C*, то проще так и написать.
В крайнем случае можно использовать слэш.
Например:
продолжительность тура **5–8 дней** (от пяти до восьми дней);
пребывание в санатории **5/8 дней** (или 5 дней, или 8 дней).

Comment: Лучше писать *слеш*, хотя Викисловарь ещё не говорит, что писать *слэш* некорректно, но он говорит, что это написание – устаревшее. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%2C+%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8D%D1%88&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3.) В конце концов, давайте вспомним, как *кэш* недавно урезали, сказав, что можно писать только *кеш*. То же и со *слешем*.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял. Насчёт вашего первого пункта похоже, что если всё так, как вы описываете, то надо ставить не тире, а дефис (вот пример из РАН-справочника, который под 5-м пунктом в 118-м параграфе: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=64#pp64), напр.: *8-9, 11-12 %, 23-24 °C.*

Если разрыв больше, чем только одна цифра, то, я думаю, надо ставить всё-таки тире, даже если значение – *или*, напр.: *5—8 дней, 20—30 %, 10—20 °C.*